# Problem using exec() function with code read in from csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, exec, quoting

I am trying to pass to Python several statements from a csv file and execute them using the `exec()` function. I am currently having a problem with a statement that I can pass into the `exec()` function as a string variable, but when I read the same value from a csv file using DataFrames I get an error.

The code that works:

```py
program = 'a = 5\nb=10\nprint("Sum =", a+b)' 
exec(program)
```

The code that does not work:

```py
trans = df.loc[df['ldms_name'] == row[2]]['translation'].item()

for i in trans.split(';'):
    exec(i)
```

The value for translation in the csv is:

```
a = 5\nb=10\nprint("Sum =", a+b)
```

the error I get is:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I have tried several different quoting methods.

Comment: You **really** must provide a [mcve]. The string you provide does not raise that error.

Comment: Line continuation errors can occur when a backslash '\' is not followed by a newline '\n'. That may help you narrow your question down a bit. Additionally if you're storing your code in a csv file you can't use commas in your code e.g. **`print(a,b)`**

Answer (score 0):

As you read the character sequence `a = 5\nb=10\nprint("Sum =", a+b)` *from a* *file*, the `\n` were not (unlike when appearing in a normal string literal) translated into a newline character, thus it gives not *the same value* as in a literal. You can rectify this by appending `.replace(r"\n", '\n')` e. g. at the end of the `trans` assignment in your *code that does not work*.

Comment: Thank you very much Armali. That fixed it.